# Java. Поиск самого частого символа в файле

Tags: java, файлы

Недавно изучаю Java, назрел вопрос.

Есть текстовый файл, в котором может встретиться любой существующий символ. Нужно найти символ, который встречается в файле чаще всего. Особенность в том что файл может быть большим(~1GB+). Как это сделать эффективно?

Моя реалицация:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"))) {
            long[] unicodeArray = new long[65536];

            while (reader.ready()) {
                char[] charArray = reader.readLine().toCharArray();
                for (char c : charArray) {
                    unicodeArray[(int) c]++;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < unicodeArray.length; i++) {
                if (unicodeArray[i] > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Symbol: " + (char) i + " Freq: " + unicodeArray[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Работает порядка минуты для файла 800мб. Я так понимаю что это не плохой результат, но в целом можно гораздо лучше.

Можно как - то улучшить код? И есть ли в этой реализации какие - нибудь косяки вплане логики? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Я думаю, можно попробовать распараллелить

Comment: Вас интересует символ (если да, то в какой кодировке?) или байт?

Comment: Поскольку реализация не соответствует поставленной задаче, то однозначно улучшить можно.

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить размер буфера у `BufferedReader` , это второй параметр конструктора.

Comment: Эникейщик, да, вы правы. Я отправил не ту версию программы. MrFylypenko, спасибо, увеличил, правда прироста по скорости не наблюдаю. Зато узнал что есть у BufferedReader такой конструктор. =)

Comment: Roman Danilov, а можно подробнее? Запустить несколько нитей для работы с файлом? Anton Shchyrov, кодировка UTF - 8. Правда в задании про это не сказано, поэтому кодировка возможно неизвестна.

Comment: Если кодировка неизвестна, то задача подсчета **символов** не решается т.к. невозможно сформировать эти символы из потока байт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы тратите время на парсинг файла через `FileReader`. Выкиньте его и используйте напрямую `FileInputStream`

Далее, вы подсчитываете символы, но ничего не говорите о кодировке файла. Пусть это будет `UTF-16BE`

```
try (InputStream reader = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
    long[] unicodeArray = new long[65536];
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    short maxChar;
    long maxCharCnt = 0;

    while ((len = reader.read(buf)) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            short c = (buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff);
            unicodeArray[c]++;
            if (unicodeArray[c] > maxCharCnt) {
                maxChar = c;
                maxCharCnt = unicodeArray[c];
        }
    }

    System.out.println((char)maxChar);
}
```

Где

```
(buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff);
```

получение двухбайтового числа из двух байт

1. `buf[i] << 8` - сдвигаем на 8 бит влево первый байт
2. `buf[i + 1] & 0xff` - т.к. результат `short`, то все операнды расширяются до этого типа, путем копирования старшего бита в добавочные. Этой операцией мы очищаем добавочные биты и оставляем исходный байт
3. `(buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff)` - Выполняем логическое ИЛИ над двумя операндами

Comment: Думаю, самым главным в чтении больших файлов является размер буфера. Его лучше сделать ка можно больше

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Первое утверждение верное, второе нет. Размер буфера должен быть **пропорционален** размеру кластера и системных буферов. Конкретный размер нужно проверять. Но больше чем 8192 байта смысла ставить нет. Прироста уже не получите

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, классная идея использовать byte[] buf. Только я не могу понять что вы в этой строке делаете, можете объяснить? short c = (buf[i] << 8) || (buf[i + 1] & 0xff); Я так понял что это: "buf[i + 1] & 0xff" оставляет только младший бит. "buf[i] << 8" это просто смещение, но почему на 8 байт и что получается в итоге?

Comment: Или поделитесь ссылкой где про это можно почитать, а то я завис на этой строке капитально.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Читать про битовые операции

Answer (score 2):

Уверен, не самый эффективный алгоритм, но лаконичный и на моей машине обрабатывает трёхгигабайтный файл за 21 секунду.

```
Map<Character, Long> chars = Files.lines(Paths.get("big.txt"))
                                  .parallel()
                                  .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
                                  .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                                  .filter(Character::isLetter)
                                  .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                                                 Collectors.counting()));

char mostFrequent = chars.entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                         .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                         .get();
```

Comment: можно немного улучшить ваше решение, дописав `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()), Collectors.counting()))
                .firstEntry()`

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, а в чем плюс?

Comment: @Flippy в возможности получить значение без второго потока, и сортировка в процессе формирования TreeMap быстрее, чем при переборе HashMap.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, понятно, спасибо)

Comment: Алгоритм конечно лаконичен, но на данный момент для меня он слишком крут. =)

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov ваш вариант вернет самый большой символ в тексте, а не самый частый (для строки "aaaaa zzz b" - "z"), т.к. карта сортирует по ключу

Comment: @zRrr точно, спасибо))