# Java. Cмещение битов

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Код взят отсюда: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844958/java-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Есть такое решение вышеупомянутой задачи `(UTF - 16BE)`:

```
try (InputStream reader = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
    long[] unicodeArray = new long[65536];
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    short maxChar;
    long maxCharCnt = 0;

    while ((len = reader.read(buf)) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            short c = (buf[i] << 8) || (buf[i + 1] & 0xff);
            unicodeArray[c]++;
            if (unicodeArray[c] > maxCharCnt) {
                maxChar = c;
                maxCharCnt = unicodeArray[c];
        }
    }

    System.out.println((char)maxChar);
}
```

Так как изучаю `Java` недавно, сложно даётся нижняя строка и намерения автора, но хочу разобраться.

```
short c = (buf[i] << 8) || (buf[i + 1] & 0xff);
```

Я понял так:

Здесь `buf[i] << 8` происходит сдвиг влево на байт, получается что младший байт состоит из нулей. Результат кастуется в int, получается подобное:

```
00000000 00000000 11101110 00000000
```

Здесь `buf[i + 1] & 0xff` "обрезаются" все байты кроме младшего(т.к 0xff == 11111111). Я не понял зачем это нужно, ведь изначально у нас и так был всего один байт. Можно было просто написать `(int)buf[i+1]`(?). Результат снова int и выйдет:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010
```

Биты от балды написал.

В итоге имеются два таких `int`. Далее применяется побитовый `OR(?)`:

```
 00000000 00000000 11101110 00000000

|

 00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010

 00000000 00000000 11101110 10101010
```

Результат: `11101110 10101010`, то есть то что написано выше без двух старших байтов?.

Я всё правильно понял?

Помимо обозначенных вопросов:

-Почему по факту это не компилируется? Ошибка: `can't apply || with (int)(int)`

-Разве так быстрее (на больших объёмах данных) чем считать из файла строку, сразу разбить её на массив `char` и работать сразу с символами?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `||` не битовая операция, а логическая. Поэтому и не компилится.

Comment: В остальном вы все верно понимаете, и да, работать с байтами быстрее чем со строками, в предложенном коде используются только примитивы, а строки это неизменяемые обьекты, которые будут нагружать GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я не понял зачем это нужно, ведь изначально у нас и так был всего один байт. Можно было просто написать `(int)buf[i+1](?)`.

Приведение производится с сохранением знака, т.е., например, байт `10101010` будет приведен к инту `11111111 11111111 11111111 10101010`.

В остальном все верно, кроме оператора `||` вместо `|` в приведенном коде - поэтому и не компилируется.

И да, побитовые операции сами по себе "быстрые", к тому же строки так устроены, что любое изменение происходит через создание новой строки(и копирование массива символов), при переводе строки в массив символов будет возвращена копия всего внутреннего массива, а не указатель на существующий массив.

Comment: По поводу неверной операции: я сейчас не у компьютера и не могу проверить наверняка, но вроде бы и с | не компилироваллсь по той же причине.

Answer (score 2):

Для кодирования UTF - 16BE используются 16 бит*, если не отводить один бит на знак, то 16 битами можно представить 65536 (2^16) значения, такое "беззнаковое" использование характерно для примитивного типа char в Java.
**Некоторые пояснения**
Используем массив

> long[] unicodeArray = new long[65536];

для хранения количества вхождений каждого из встретившихся символов.
Цикл

> while((len = reader.read(buf)) > 0) {}

последовательно считывает байты в массив byte[] buf, когда читать нечего, read возвращает -1 и цикл прерывается. Для обработки считанных в массив buf данных, используется цикл

> for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {}

Выражение

> char c = (char)((buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff));

формирует 16 битное представления символа(16 бит = 2 байта) из считанных в данных. Буфер buf это массива байт, т.е нам нужно брать по два байта из массива и "склеивать" их, для. "Логика склеивания" следующая.

Предположим что: buf[i] содержит последовательность бит (это один байт из файла)

> 10000001 (-127)

При использовании побитовых операторов происходит неявное преобразование типов к int. При преобразовании в int получим

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000001

Выражение

> (buf[i] << 8)

выполняет сдвиг влево на 8 бит, получаем

> 11111111 11111111 10000001 00000000

Мы получили первый байт, смещенный на 8 бит влево, т.е. освободили место для второго байта

Далее предположим buf[i+1] содержит значение последовательность бит

> 10000000 (-128)

при преобразовании в int получим (расширение учитывает знак)

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000

Выражение

> (buf[i + 1] & 0xff)

побитно перемножает

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000 - получено из buf[i+1]
>
> &
>
> 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 - это 0xff в двоичной форме
>
> =
>
> 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000

В результате второй байт расположен в последних 8 битах

Далее

> (buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff)

складывает  преобразованный и смещенный первый байт (из buf[i]) и подготовленный второй (из buf[i+1])

> 11111111 11111111 10000001 00000000
>
> |
>
> 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000
>
> =
>
> 11111111 11111111 10000001 10000000

Полученное значение имеет размерность int, оно явно преобразуется в char(отсекаются первые 16 бит, если считать слева направо) и сохраняется в переменной **char с** .
В результате получаем то, что хотели ("склееные" два байта)

> 10000001 10000000

Полученное значение используется как "адрес символа" в массиве, и производится инкремент "счетчика" для данного символа

> unicodeArray[c]++;

Вот такой код работает.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream ;
import java.io.InputStream ;
import java.io.IOException ;

public class MaxFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (InputStream reader = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
            //массив примитивных типов long
            //для хранения количества вхождений каждого из встретившихся символов
            long[] unicodeArray = new long[65536];
            //массив для хранения считанных данных
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            //сколько байт прочитали в буфер
            int len;
            //самый часто встречающийся символ
            char maxChar = 0;
            //количество вхождений самого часто встречающегося символа
            long maxCharCnt = 0;
            //в цикле читаем данные в буфер, пока не закончатся данные (read вернет -1)
            while ((len = reader.read(buf)) > 0) {
                //в цикле обрабабатываем по 2 байта из буфера,
                //из которых формируют один символ в UTF - 16 
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                    //формирум 16 битное представления из считанных байт
                    //при использовании побитовых операторов
                    //(buf[i] << 8) - сдвиг первый байт на 8 бит влево
                    //"освобождает" место для второго байта
                    //(buf[i + 1] & 0xff) "готовит" второй байт 
                    //унарные операторы преобразуют тип к int
                    //преобразуем в тип char (отсекая первые 16 бит слева)
                    char c = (char)((buf[i] << 8) | (buf[i + 1] & 0xff));
                    //используем char (диапазон значений от 0 до 65536) как адрес в массиве,
                    //и увеличивая счетчик для соответствующего символа
                    unicodeArray[c]++;
                    //если больше текущего максимума, обновляем максимум
                    if (unicodeArray[c] > maxCharCnt) {
                        maxChar = c;
                        maxCharCnt = unicodeArray[c];
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println((char)maxChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KirstenLy **Почитайте справку**: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)